# Переход между активностями на разных версиях Android

Tags: java, android

Реализовал простой пример показа окна About. Переходом из MainActivity в AboutActivity.

Класс:

```
package com.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AboutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    }
}
```

Переход:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Манифест:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AboutActivity"
    android:label="@string/action_settings_about"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    >
</activity>
```

На реальном устройстве с версией андроида 4.2, которое использую для отладки все работает. Но недавно обнаружил, что на устройстве с 6.0 в приложении с плеймаркета наблюдается вылет.

Comment: Без логово падения не помочь. Добавьте их в вопрос и покажите на какой строке кода падает

Comment: И зачем здесь манифест?

Comment: Логов нет, под рукой одно устройство, на котором все работает.  Проц амд, поэтому с эмулятором траблы. Манифест, если не объявить активность, будет падать. Переделал всё с использованием фрагментов, когда разберусь в чем была проблема, отпишу.

Comment: можно подключить `crashlytics` это поможет вам увидеть логи и место где программа падает